# How to easily duplicate a Windows Form in Visual Studio?

Tags: winforms, visual-studio

How can I easily duplicate a C#/VB Form in Visual Studio? If I copy & paste in the Solution Explorer, it uses the same class internally and gets messed up. How do you do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Copying winforms between projects in Visual Studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/863582/copying-winforms-between-projects-in-visual-studio)

Answer (score 61, accepted):

I usually copy the files in windows explorer, open them up in Notepad/Wordpad and just change the one mention of the class name at the top. Include those files in your project, and you'll be good to go.

Comment: Thank you. This is the most practical since I have no "Base Class" functionality, only little "template" like features customized that I won't like to do again manually.

Comment: C#/VB.NET let you inherit forms just like any other class, so if you have just a common template...

Comment: worked like a charm....VS is a PITA, they should make the copy work in VS, THANKS for the solution!!!!

Comment: A note for VB forms: This works easily, but if you have a .Designer.vb, you need to do a search and replace on the name change to fix the link to ComponentResourceManager (.resx) file.
The bulk replace in the .vb code file also updates all the control event handler Sub names, which improves readability ...

Comment: While Add->Existing Item, first needs to add  .designer & then .cs file individually as mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/863582/copying-winforms-between-projects-in-visual-studio

Comment: I renamed 4 files after copying and used a text editor on 3 of the files (.vb, .designer.vb and .resx). The 4th file was a binary .resources file that also contained the original form name internally and it was updated on the next rebuild all.

Answer (score 23):

1. Copy and paste the form.
2. Rename the pasted form .cs to match the new form class name.  This should auto rename other related files.
3. Open up .cs file.  Change the class name and the name of the constructor(s) and destructor.
4. Open up .Designer.cs file and change the class name.

Extra Credit:

5. Consider abstracting common functionality from the form into common form or controls.

Comment: No need to change the class name, at least if you work with VB 2012(just tested it ;) )

Comment: this worked well with me on VS 2010 and c#. Also if we have datagridview controls on it, I recommend having a peak at Designer.cs of the newly created form because sometimes it can rename our columns object names, but general it works really pretty!

Answer (score 11):

Secured way without problems is to make **Template** of your form
You can use it in the same project or any other project. and you can add it very easily, such as adding a new form . Here's a way how make **Template**

1- from **File** Menu click **Export Template**

2- Choose Template Type  (Choose item template ) and click next

3-Check Form that you want to make a template of it, and click next **Twice**

4-Rename your template and (put describe , choose icon image ,preview image if you want)

5-click finish

Now you can add new item and choose your template in any project

Comment: This is my preferred way of copying a form as it eliminates any regression errors caused by renaming. Note in VS2017 the Export Template command has been moved to the Projects menu. And due to a bug, when you choose to automatically import the new template you will need to close and re-open VS2017 for the template to appear.

Comment: Yes the issue was finally solved in vs2015 with template zips. I like it because it can stack "new general use dialogs" in the proper place quickly which is New Item !

Answer (score 10):

I have been using another way of copying forms since vb6.

1. File Menu / SE - Save CurrentForm.cs as - NewForm.cs
2. Change its Name to NewForm in Properties window.
3. In Solution Explorer - Add Existing Item - CurrentForm.cs
4. Usually in MDI form (where CurrentForm is referred) - CurrentFormToolStripMenuItem_Click event - change reference back to CurrentForm (which is automatically changed to NewForm in step 1).

comments welcome.

Comment: Thanks this is the only method that work with out issues for me!

Comment: I agree with Ross, this way is all done within visual studio so it's well contained. This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: It works but be careful with the renaming in the Properties window, it will propagate throughout the solution.

Comment: This one works best. Thanks.

Comment: Seven years later, this is still the simplest solution.

Answer (score 5):

1. Add a sub-folder to your project.
2. Right-click on the sub-folder, and click Add Existing Item.
3. Browse to the form you want to copy, and select its .cs file.  This will duplicate the original form (partial and resx and all) in the sub-folder.  The name will not conflict with the original, because the sub-folder will be included in its namespace.
4. Right-click on the .cs file, click Refactor | Rename and enter the new name.  This will also rename the partial and the resx for you.

I'm generally averse to methods of doing this that involve opening up the files in notepad or whatever, since I always think a common task like this should have a built-in way of doing it in Visual Studio.  In this case, there is.

Comment: This didn't work for me at all.....it kept the original namespace and then gave a weird error of xxxx.MainForm.resources was specified more than once in the "Resources" parameter.  Duplicate items are not supported by the Resources parameter

Answer (score 3):

First of all, if you're duplicating a lot of forms with cut and paste, consider a common base class for your forms (or for a category of your forms) that implements shared/common functionality or look & feel elements.  You can also create a template for new forms that meet your needs and create new forms from that template.

Personally I just cut and paste then fix any lingering name errors.  Since I abstract out common functionality, I have not felt enough pain to look for a better way ;-)

Answer (score 2):

1. Right-Click on Form -> Copy Class

[image]

2. Right click on destination Folder and Paste Class

[image]

3. Rename new Form and say yes to renaming all references to this class.

[image]

Comment: I don't see this option "Copy Class" .. I'm using VS 2017 Comunity. Is that a feature available only for paid versions of VS ?

Comment: I'm not using the paid version either. I'm not sure what the criteria are for this context menu item to be available.

Answer (score 2):

If you're working in VS 2019, take a few minutes to create an item template -- it's a perfect solution.  [How to: Create item templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-create-item-templates?view=vs-2019)

Not sure if it applies to earlier versions of VS.

Answer (score 2):

1. Press "Ctrl" and drag your mouse to duplicate a existing form class file.
2. Then exlude the existing form class file from the project.
3. Rename the new form class file. Go to code behind, rename the class name
   and its related reference together.
4. Include back the previous existing form class file of project
5. Done

Answer (score 1):

Its Really Easy. "In Design mode FORM"  (form1.cs[Design])  copy the whole Form "ctrl A" then  ctrl C. All objects at once.   Then add a new windows form to the project. Change the size of the form to the size that you want then paste ctrl V all of the new objects will be copied to the new form. When they are all still picked double click on any of the objects.   NOT THE FORM!!!..... This will create the code on the Form side matching the objects you just pasted. if it doesn't you can double click on each object and it will create the code one at a time. I use a text box area to double click in and it works almost every time.
I use this method everyday WORKS GREAT.

Comment: No, this copies the *objects*, not the form.

Answer (score 0):

Just rename the class the designer references.

But a better solution is to create a new instance of the same class at run time.

Or better yet, create a parent form that various implementations inherit from.

Answer (score 0):

1.Add a new folder to your project

2.Copy the form into that

3.Change the name in properties as well as change the file name

4.Check each form for their class name (they shouldn't be same)

Answer (score 0):

(replicated this answer from my other post in case someone is looking for this solution here)

Using VS2013 just tested this and it appears reliable and consistent.  This is similar to some comments above but adds another method that's quicker.

**(1st)** In Windows File Explorer highlight and copy all 3 Form files (.vb or .cs, .designer, .resx)

**(2nd)** This can be accomplished 2 ways:

(2a-1) In File Explorer paste the 3 files into the project folder with your other forms

(2a-2) In VS Solution Explorer, turn 'Show All Files' on, Right Click on the pasted form & 'Include in Project'.  It should work without other changes.

**Or, I think better:**

(2b-1) In VS, click into Solution Explorer and paste w/Control-C. (For some reason the right-click context menu in Solution Explorer may not show a paste option, but it works from the keyboard.)  This method adds the form to the project directly without having to 'Include in Project' as above.  With this method you can add as many forms at a time as you like (all 3 files for each) in a single step.

Answer (score 0):

- Save the all project
- Right click in the Solution Explorer (SE), "Copy"
- Right click on the project name in the SE (this is the first line), "Paste". It will create a "Copy of .....vb" form
- Right click on this new form in SE, "View code", and change its class name to the name, that you wanna use for the Form
- Left click on the new form in SE and rewrite its name for the one, that you used in the class name (and .vb in the end)
- Build - if it has no error, you win! :)

Answer (score 0):

This process may take one or two minutes...

- Create a new project.
- Copy the form's files to the new project's folder.
- Include the form in the new project.
- Rename the form.
- Rename its class name in the code behind file.
- Rename constructor name in the code behind file.
- Rename class name in the designer file.
- Bring the changed form's files back in the folder of original project and include it.

Answer (score 0):

For VS2022

Visual Studio does a tremendous amount for us "under the covers"; use that rather the various copy & paste approaches.  The template approach ensures all necessary components are included.

**Projects Menu** -> **Export Template**

in the wizard:

1. select **Export Item** & **source project**
2. click **Next**
3. select desired form cs from list
4. click **Next**
5. **ignore** Select Item References; click **Next**
6. **Name** defaults to project name; change it -- it is displayed in Add Item dialogue
7. add a description
8. ensure **Automatically Import** into VS is **checked** (the default)
9. click **Finish**

"**Projects Menu** -> **Add New Item**" to load the template.

**Rename form in Solution Explorer** ("right" click to get Context Menu).  Even if you only use the template for a single duplication this approach actually takes less time than the copy & paste approaches with the added benefit of being available to other solutions/projects.

**Important**:  As of this writing it is still necessary to exit and restart VS in order for the template to be listed in the Add Item dialogue.

Answer (score -1):

Inherit the form!

Comment: I +1'd this purely on the basis that it is the best solution. Is this correct? It would work fine surely?

Comment: yep, have a base form and everything on the base form would appear in the form that inherited it.

Comment: @Jon
Inheriting is not a practical solution, as it prevents you from directly editing inherited control inside the form..