# Generating forums from Source code (Visual basic 2008 express)?

Tags: vb.net

I have never used Visual Basic before, or any GUI programming languages (i've only programmed console applications), and i was recently given the source code to another programmer's Visual Basic program (with a GUI) to debug, now when programming C++ console applications i'd merely copy the source into the compiler, edit it, and compile it, however when attempting to do that with visual basic code, i copy the source into the compiler (the source was contained in a microsoft word document), and the code doesn't compile nor does the "designer" design the program form visually at all (i have a copy of the compiled program as well).

I am confused as to why copying the source code into a compiler does not auto generate the form (visual aspect of the program) when i was given the source code to a program that does infact have a GUI and why it gives me a series of errors and will not compile at all (i assume these errors are related to the GUI that is not being generated when i copy the source into the compiler because they are "eventhandler" type errors).

I know this is a very simply question, but i haven't been able to find any answers because this isn't exactly an orthodox way to go about programming i know or an easy question to phrase, but it's what i was asked to do and i am at a loss because i've never done programming with a GUI, So what am i missing? is the source code for generating the GUI independent of the program source code?

I would greatly appreciate any help at all, thank you for your time.

Comment: This might help you 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1268591/how-to-easily-duplicate-a-windows-form-in-visual-studio

Answer (score 0):

If the source you have contains a ".vbproj" file open that in visual studio and it SHOULD load the rest of the projects files, from there run the project.

IF however you do not have a project file for the source you can always create a new VB project and copy/paste the sources accordingly.